# Building x64 SQLite with spatiaLite?

Tags: .net, spatialite, visual-studio, sqlite, 64bit

I need a spatial-enabled SQLite solution for a x64 Windows application I am developing.

I have examined and downloaded and attempted to compile the SQLite amalgamation package; I've looked at the cSharpSqlite package; I've downloaded the *System.Data.SQLite* source.
The cSharpSqlite package I can at least compile, but none of the others. I am using VS2012 Professional.

There is *so* much outdated, confusing, incomplete and just plain incorrect information on how to build a x64 SQLite library that can load extensions. Half of the comments on SE about this are unanswered, or with a few comments that are now no longer up to date.

Can you list some simple steps to show me?
(Or link to a binary that I obviously couldn't find?)

Comment: This seems to still be the case 5 years later. Or is it a secret only c devs know?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the spatialite binary from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/

You can download the .net assemblies from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki, or just use NuGet after reading which bits you need.

Open the connection, enable extension loading, and then load the SpatiaLite extension using `SELECT load_extension()`.

Comment: I presume that devs who are used to working with some magic language (c?) know what your answer means. Being a JavaScript and Flutter dev I have no idea what it means. Can we have a version of this answer for dummies please?

Comment: @Alex The question asked for a .net / visual studio answer. It matches what a C# developer would know.